# How to run function after reload to another page from special link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if I redirected from special link ?

I have two link list:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="item"><a href="/offer">Offer</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<ul class="special-menu">
    <li class="item"><a href="/offer">Offer</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to know, if I went to for example /offer from ul.special-menu and run specialFunction();

How can I do that in JS ?

Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: you can check the href then do conditional statement

Comment: @guradio yes, You're right, but I have two lists with the same href for items - sorry. I updated my question now. I want to run my function only if I come from ul.special-menu

Comment: same goes just check the parent `$('ul').hasClass('special-menu');`

Comment: I want to run function after redirect to href, so click>reaload>run function and here I want to know which menu used in previus page to redirect here.

Comment: I don't know why you want that, but you can use `localStorage` to save flag, or use hash (#) in url for the special menu. Then check when loading page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would append a query string onto the urls inside 'special-menu'.

As so: `<li class="item"><a href="/offer?qs=specialMenu">Offer</a></li>`

Then on the offers page you can get the query string and save it as a variable, then process it how you wish.

```
var qs = location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, '');
if (qs === "specialMenu") {
 specialFunction();
}
else {
// do something else
}
```

Comment: Close, but You help me to use url from browser: if (window.location.href.indexOf("specialMenu") > -1){runFunction();}. Thanks!